# Deserialize file from multipart post request in Flask

Tags: python, html, file, flask

In my HTML I have the following code:

```
<form action="editprojects" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="pdf"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Now in my Flask I have the endpoint:

```
@app.route('/editprojects',methods=['GET','POST'])
def editProjects():

    pdf = request.files['pdf']

    with open('mypdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf)
```

All files seem to be corrupted and ~ 52 bytes, so there must be some content. I've tried converting to `String`, trying `w` and `wb`, I've also seen errors like `must be convertible to a buffer not FileStorage`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `pdf.save(path, filename)` ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Now it seems to just write a file with `0 bytes`, for some reason. EDIT: fixed.

Comment: Please check the file size and the file encoding !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks. I got it to work !

Comment: You are welcome. The solution was ? :D

Comment: @GregPeckory .. Either Post your finding as an answer or delete..and it's better the former as we might spot more in depth issue than you would anticipated.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Yes, you're solution worked. I forgot to restart the server, but after I restarted it it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IsmailRBOUH mentioned, this fixed my problem:

```
pdf.save(path, filename) // path is optional
```

This is because `request.files` gives a file instead of a string or bytes, therefore you can just save the file.